# Including a plain text file with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, include, document, plaintext, xslt-1.0

How can I include the content of a plain text file in a result document from within an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet? I.e., just like `document()`, but without parsing it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="magic-method-to-include-plaintext(@xlink_href)" />
```

I am *almost* sure, that this doesn't work without extension, because:

1. there is a special XPath function defined for this in XSLT/XPath 2.0:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text(@xlink:href, 'UTF-8')"/>
   ```
2. the XSLT FAQ only lists a [Java extension](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4760.html#d6062e292) to achieve this via EXSLT

However, perhaps I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, perhaps I missed something?

**No, XSLT 1.0 cannot access the content of a non-xml text file without using an extension function**.

One way around this is to pass the string as a global parameter to the transformation.

Comment: I am trying to access an xml file.  But only use one node in the xml file instead of including the whole file itself.  So how do i parse/traverse the file in xsl and only display that one node?