# XSLT reading values from property file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing an xstl file.
I want to set Minimum and maximum threshold for values in XML.
Lets say I have

```
<metric id="M12">12.00</metric>
```

Here I want to check that value of `M12` should be within range of **5-12**.

I am setting these threshold values manually in XSL.
But now I want these threshold values should be read from some `.properties` file.

Is it possible to read value from `.properties` file from XSL file?

**If yes, how can I read the threshold values set in `.properties` file?**

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326138/how-to-read-a-properties-file-inside-a-xsl-file

Answer (score 0):

**Use the standard XSLT `document()` function to dynamically obtain an XML document, having its URI**.

If the .properties file isn't an XML file but a text file, it can be read in XSLT 2.0 using the standard XSLT 2.0 function **[`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text)**.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties, how is `document()` usefull in retrieving data from a non-xml file? I'll be happy to learn something from a demonstration…

Comment: @Renaud, The OP hasn't explained that the file isn't an XML file. If the file doesn't contain a well-formed XML document, it still can be read with XSLT 2.0 using the standard function `unparsed-text()`.