# Display URL in Xslt File from multiple envoirnments

Tags: variables, xslt, dynamic-url

Hi I'm trying to remove a hard-coded URL from an xslt file to allow the xslt to be used across 3 environments.

Currently this is how it is in my XSLT

```
<URL>Https://Website1.net<xsl:value-of select="URL"/></URL>
```

This file will be used in other environments so i want to know is there a way i could read the value from a config file or a global.asa so it might read like

```
<URL>variableValue<xsl:value-of select="URL"/></URL>
```

And allow for automatic deployments without worrying about the environment.
Or is this even possible ?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how is your solution but maybe you can pass a parameter to the stylesheet.

It can be done easily and on your stylesheet you only change this

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="environment"></xsl:param>
    <URL><xsl:value-of select="$environment"/><xsl:value-of select="URL"/></URL>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you need a properties file you can check this post [how to read properties file inside xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326138/how-to-read-a-properties-file-inside-a-xsl-file)