# XSL - Externalizing Xpath queries to a property file

Tags: xpath, spring-integration, xslt-2.0, saxon

I went through various posts, regarding reading properties from external property files. Looks like there is a function - getProperty, which can read values from a property file, using a key. I am using saxon parser with spring integration.  I am trying something like this, as described in the post :-

spring context file:

```
   <int-xml:xslt-transformer id="xsltTransformer" input-channel="bulkStringInboundChannel"
    output-channel="toBridgeChannel" result-type="StringResult" **transformer-factory-class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"**
    xsl-resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/intake/intake-flow/bulkTransformer.xsl" />
```

XSL style sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
....
 <xsl:variable name="props" select="document('prop.xml')" />
 <xsl:value-of select="f:getProperty('query1')"/>
....
```

Prop.xml:

```
query1 = /Batch/RequestID/text()
```

> Error description:
>     XPST0003: XPath syntax error at char 23 on line 30 in **{f:getProperty('query1')}:**
>   XTSE0650: No template exists named getProperty

I now have two questions- first of all, how do I get rid of these errors?

Second, can I store xPath queries in property files? The post describes a method, to read a property file and use the value pertaining to its key. However, I am thinking that getProperty will just print the query's text equivalent instead of evaluating the query and processing it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Post - [How to read a .properties file inside a .xsl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326138/how-to-read-a-properties-file-inside-a-xsl-file)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the Spring side of the question, but as for the Saxon side, you can call the JDK method System.getProperty() using code like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="System:getProperty('user.dir')" xmlns:System="java:java.lang.System"/>
```

Java extensibility requires Saxon-PE or higher.

If the value of the property that you read is an XPath expression, you can then execute it using the XSLT 3.0 xsl:evaluate instruction - which also requires Saxon-PE or higher.