# How to read a .properties file inside a .fo file?

Tags: xsl-fo

The problem is as follows:
I have a .fo file, where I print some personal data text, like an address, from a generated xml file.
The country in the xml-file is not the exact country, but the country-code (like EN, DE, FR and such).
I have another file country.properties where I match those country-codes with their actual name. Format is as follows:

```
country.EN=England
country.FR=France
...
```

Now I want to show the matched name in my generated file, but I didn't find any way how to access.

In my research I found this
[How to read a .properties file inside a .xsl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326138/how-to-read-a-properties-file-inside-a-xsl-file)
and read a lot in https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/ but I didn't get any idea the whole day.

At the end of the day, I doubt this is even possible, but maybe some of you faced a similar problem and are able to help.

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?  Also, Java supports property files in an XML format.  It would be slightly easier for your XSLT to work with your property files if the property files were in the XML format.

Comment: @TonyGraham is correct. You could create a super simple code that reads the properties file and outputs an XML file, with a <country> element for each of those lines (even parsing them apart like <country abbr="EN" text="England"/> then use that XML as a lookup in your other XSLT.

Comment: I was suggesting more that the defined XML format for properties could be an option. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html. Converting property files to XML is simple only in the simple cases (such as in this question). Property files are ISO 8859-1, with 'unicode escapes' for other characters, and properties can have leading white-space, span multiple lines, or omit the property value. You would want at least XSLT 2.0. You could use Java to convert to XML property files (but lose comments): see, e.g., https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/convert-properties-to-xml/.

Comment: Thanks guys, but unfortunately i'm fully bound to the given format, since it is used somewhere else i can't touch. I have to use XSLT 1 aswell.